# Is it okay to do axios call in setInterval?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am aware that it might have some kind of ram leak or something for constantly calling on API for status. I am going to do a live status update when you login into third party application. I have all the API tho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're able to I would recommend using Websockets, websockets are best suited for when a client needs to react quickly to a change (especially one it cannot predict). Websockets are commonly used for real-time chat applications. You can view documentation on it here: [JS WebSocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket).

Comment: I wanted to do that but the backend server is built with C#, Dotnet and I have no control over the source code. I just wanted to know that constantly checking on API is recommended or not. I think that is my only solution :')))

Comment: So in your scenario I would use web workers [link](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/running-fetch-in-a-web-worker-700dc33ac854), to get the requests off the main thread. I know browser support isn't that great thought for it, otherwise theres not really a way around the setinterval solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.
To find out leaks you should do memory profiling if that's the concern.